# Facebook iframe application after authorization redirect to facebook page tab

Tags: php, tabs, facebook, authorization

I have problems with redirecting user after authorization back to the app tab in facebook page. I always end up in standalone application canvas page.

> **Edit:**
>   It was meant to be an app in tab
>   within a Fb page. I wanted to do the
>   authorization and then to redirect
>   user back to page tab. But when you do
>   this the tab looks just like before
>   and it seems to user like an error
>   because he came from authorization and
>   the app in tab looks the same. He has
>   to click on it to get some kind of
>   response or message.

Is there any example that can be downloaded or some kind of step-by-step tutorial. Here is my code:

```
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));

//Facebook Authentication part
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
        'canvas'    => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        )
);

$uid = null; //facebook user id
$fbme = null;

if (!$session) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}
else {
    try {
        $uid  = $facebook->getUser();
        $fbme = $facebook->api('/me?fields[]=id&fields[]=last_name&fields[]=first_name');
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: What _Facebook_ class are you using ? why do you go with JS redirection when PHP can do it ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I'm using PHP-SDK. JS redirection is there because this is all in Iframe within Facebook page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind I've done authorization using Ajax within Page tab. This method is also described in question "[Facebook fan page tab and user id.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537955/facebook-fan-page-tab-and-user-id/2780143#2780143)":

```
<div id="intro">
    <a onclick="load_iframe();"><img src="<?php echo $fbconfig['baseUrl'], 'intro.jpg' ?>" /></a>
</div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function load_iframe()
    {
        var intro = document.getElementById('intro');
        var root = document.getElementById('fb-root');

        var ajax = new Ajax();
        ajax.responseType = Ajax.FBML;
        ajax.onerror = function(error)
        {
            new Dialog().showMessage("Alert", "Required authorization.","Close");
        };

        ajax.ondone = function(data)
        {
            intro.setStyle('display', 'none');
            root.setInnerFBML(data);
        }
        ajax.requireLogin = true;
        ajax.post("<?php echo $fbconfig['baseUrl'] ?>iframe.php");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What does $fbconfig['baseUrl'] stand for in your example?

Comment: It holds the app URL on my server (canvas) e.g. http://example.tld/facebook/myapp/